# Formatar data DD-MM-YYYY string jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um campo **'DATAADMISSAO'** que recebe informações do DB no formato abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de inputar no seguinte padrão: DD-MM-YYYY.

Segue abaixo, o javascript que insere os dados no campo:

```
function setSelectedZoomItem(selectedItem) {
    var info = selectedItem.type.split("___");

    if (info.length > 1) { }

    if(selectedItem.type == "filiais"){
        $("#filial").val(selectedItem['nomefantasia']);
        $("#cnpj").val(selectedItem['cgc']);
        $("#codfilial").val(selectedItem['codfilial']);                         
    }else if(selectedItem.type == "setores"){
        $("#setor").val(selectedItem['nomefantasia']);              
    }else if(selectedItem.type == "chapafunc"){
        $("#chapafuncionario").val(selectedItem['CHAPA']);
        $("#nomefuncionario").val(selectedItem['NOME']);
        $("#cargofuncionario").val(selectedItem['FUNCAO']);
        $("#dataadmissao").val(selectedItem['DATAADMISSAO']);
        $("#salariofuncionario").val(selectedItem['SALARIO']);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Além do método já citado de criar um objeto do tipo data, você também pode simplesmente formatar a string com uma expressão regular, dessa maneira:

```js
var data = '2016-12-08 00:00:00.0';
var dataFormatada = data.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*).*/, '$3-$2-$1');
console.log(dataFormatada);
```

Comment: Melhor solução da internet! \o/

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso, vou oferecer o meu jeito que pode ser um pouco complicado.

```js
$("#dataadmissao").change(function() {
  var data = new Date($(this).val()); //cria um objeto de data com o valor inserido no input
  data = data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'); // converte em uma string de data no formato pt-BR
  $(this).val(data); // insere o novo valor no input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='dataadmissao'></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma seria utilizando a função [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) do javascript:

```js
let data = "2016-12-08 00:00:00.0"; 
let split = data.split(' '); //separa a data da hora
let formmated = split[0].split('-');

console.log(formmated[2]+'-'+formmated[1]+'-'+formmated[0]);
```